# What is the difference between on() and addListener() in Node.js events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm a bit confused about the difference between `on()` and `addListener()` in Node.js events. any explanation that clarifies the differences?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:web] when it seems to have nothing to do with any kind of web and the tag says "DO NOT USE"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There **is no**  difference

[The documentation lists `.on` and `.addListener` as an alias](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener)

One thing that I'll point out is in the documentation it does state that `.on` returns an Event Emitter, whereas `addListener` does not specifically state this.

This is just an oversight, and in fact if you type the code out it's easy to see:

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const myEE = new EventEmitter();
let a = myEE.on("foo",()=>{});
let b = myEE.addListener("foo",()=>{});

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Both these logs will print the same thing, and you'll see something analogous to the following:

```
EventEmitter {
  domain: Domain {
    domain: null,
    _events: { error: [ Function: debugDomainError ] },
    _eventsCunt: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    members: []
  },
  _events: { foo: [ [ Function ], [ Function ] ] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined
}
```

So **no**. There are no differences between them.

Answer (score 3):

`on` is an alias for `addEventListener`

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener

Answer (score 2):

[As per documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener), they are just aliases, so there is no difference.

See also [how they are defined](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/91adbe14b4490483785e1cd094c1130278cd25f3/lib/events.js#L270-L274) in the lib.